# Replacing String in String Corona SDK

Tags: string, sdk, lua, coronasdk, lua-patterns

Problem: I have a string like such: 
          `"this is a !a joke !/a! haha"`
The problem is that I want to replace the part `"!a joke !/a!"`                            However, the problem is that I cannot use string.replace() since the part between `"!a and !/a!"` changes so sometimes it may be `"!a happy !/a!"` or sometimes it may be `"!a cheer !/a!"` and so on.... My question is how can I replace this string if all that stays the same is `!a` and `!/a`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`string.gsub`](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/string/gsub.html) with lua string-patterns:

```
string.gsub("this is a !a joke !/a! haha", "!a %a+ !/a!", "cheer")
```

If need be you can even capture the string that's between `!a`:

```
local str = "this is a !a joke !/a! haha"
str:gsub ("!a (%a+) !/a!", "sad %1")
```

Which after substitution gives you `"this is a sad joke haha"`.

See the [Lua reference manual 6.4.1 - Patterns](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#6.4.1) for other patterns and character classes available.

Comment: Thank you! The second example is what I needed because I wasn't sure how to handle changing text between two specific strings that I was looking for.